# Solving Knights Tour using Warnsdorff's Rule

Tags: ruby, algorithm, knights-tour

I'm currently trying to improve upon a brute force implementation of Knight's Tour by using Warnsdorff's Rule, however I feel as though I'm not understanding the algorithm, as the execution of the script is taking very long. I'm mainly looking for hints to point me in the right direction so that I can figure as much of this out on my own as possible. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
class KnightsTour
    def initialize
        board = [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
        8.times do |i|
            board[i] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        end
        tour(0,0,board)
    end

    def tour(x,y,board,current_move=0)
        current_move +=1
        board[x][y] = current_move

        puts board if current_move == 64
        exit if current_move == 64

        ordered_neighbors = 
            neighbors(x,y,board).sort_by { |m| m[:weight] }

        ordered_neighbors.each do |move|
            tour(move[:x], move[:y], Marshal.load(Marshal.dump board), current_move)
        end
        false
    end

    def weight(x,y,board)
        possible = 0
        moves(x,y).each do |move|
            next unless valid_move?(move, board)
            possible +=1
        end
        possible
    end

    def neighbors(x,y,board)
        neighbors = []
        moves(x,y).each do |move|
            next unless valid_move?(move, board)
            neighbors << { weight: weight(move[:x], move[:y], board), 
                                x: move[:x], y: move[:y] }
        end
        neighbors
    end

    def valid_move?(move,board)
        x = move[:x]
        y = move[:y]
        !(board[x] == nil || board[x][y] == nil || 
          board[x][y] != 0 || x < 0 || y < 0)
    end

    def moves(x,y)
        [{x: x+2, y: y-1}, 
         {x: x+1, y: y-2}, 
         {x: x-1, y: y-2}, 
         {x: x-1, y: y+2}, 
         {x: x+1, y: y+2}, 
         {x: x-2, y: y+1}, 
         {x: x-2, y: y-1}]
    end
end

KnightsTour.new
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Optimisation

I would be suspicious of the time spent in:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump board)
```

An alternative to this is to use a single copy of the board.

At the start of tour you set:

```
board[x][y] = current_move
```

so if at the end of tour you clear it with:

```
board[x][y] = 0
```

then you should not need to make copies of board.

### Bug

Note that a Knight has 8 legal moves!

Try adding:

```
{x: x+2, y: y+1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot that 8th move considering I have all 8 written down in front of me. After making your changes the program successfully executes in the blink of an eye.